# Implementing IList<T> and IReadOnlyList<T> in F#

Tags: f#

I would like to implement these two interfaces for my `struct` in F#, but they share a lot of members in common. According to the documentation I found, I will have to implement both interfaces explicitly.

Is there any way in F# to implement them without repeating the implementation of the common members?

Comment: Why do you want to implement these interfaces in the first place? I'm not saying that there's *no* case where this is appropriate, but F# already gives you native lists, arrays, and `seq`...

Comment: f# lists are not IList<T>, they are more similar to ML lists. In addition, I want my lists to be mutable.

Comment: The .NET framework design guidelines [warn against making value types mutable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229031).

Comment: @MarkSeemann, I know. However, in my case I believe it is necessary. I am creating a lot of such objects and I want them to be structs. It already improved the performance of my app a lot, after it spent a lot of time in GC. In addition, these objects are slices into a multi-dimensional structure (something like array + index + stride +size), so essentially the original structure is mutable. These objects are just "proxies" to mutate parts of it.

Answer (score 4):

The approach that I feel would work well in your scenario is to put the actual implementations as regular, non-interface members. Then for interface implementations just reexpose those members. Something like:

```
 member this.GetEnumerator() = ... // actual logic goes here
 ... // other members     

 interface IList<T> with
     member this.GetEnumerator() = this.GetEnumerator()
     ... // other members

 interface IReadOnlyList<T> with
     member this.GetEnumerator() = this.GetEnumerator()
     ... // other members
```